# Redux isn't updating my property so my component has no data

Tags: redux, react-redux

I am trying to make sure my component loads data and show it on the screen

I have the following code in my component

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getRecipeList();
}
```

It will basically go and fetch data for me in an action.

In my reducer I have

```
case GET_RECIPE_LIST:
    return {
        ...state, RecipeList: action.RecipeList
    };
```

And in my container I have

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    RecipeList: state.RecipeList
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
    getRecipeList: () => dispatch(getRecipeList())
})

const RecipeListContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(RecipeList)
```

And my reducer

```
import { 
    SELECT_RECIPE,
    ADD_RECIPE_INGREDIENTS_TO_GROCERYLIST,
    GET_RECIPE_LIST
 } from '../Actions/ActionTypes';

const recipeReducer = (state = {Recipe: null, RecipeList: []}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SELECT_RECIPE:
            return {
                ...state, Recipe: action.Recipe
            };
        case ADD_RECIPE_INGREDIENTS_TO_GROCERYLIST: 
            return {...state};
        case GET_RECIPE_LIST:
            return {
                ...state, RecipeList: action.RecipeList
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default recipeReducer;
```

My action

```
export const selectRecipe = id => {
  const settings = appConfig;
  return (dispatch) => {
     fetch(`${settings.RestServerLocation}/Api/recipe/${id}`)
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then((data) => {
        /* return {
          type: SELECT_RECIPE,
          Recipe: data
        } */
        dispatch( {
          type: SELECT_RECIPE,
          Recipe: data
        })
      }); 
  }
}
```

How come when I dispatch `getRecipeList` my property `RecipeList` isn't getting loaded? BTW if I put a breakpoint in the reducer I can see the data is there

Comment: Please add createStore defination

Comment: can you attach the `state` object definition along with `reducer` bindings ?

Comment: const store = createStore(combineReducer,
    applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)
  );

Comment: @Mok defination of  combineReducer too

Comment: Thanks. I added the reducer to the code above

Comment: maybe have a close look at this example and follow your calls to compare?
https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/async

Comment: This is probably better. I'll investigate myself and post back my findings

Comment: So the issue was because I was using combineReducer and had to do:

`const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        RecipeList: state.recipeReducer.RecipeList
    }
}`